# how to get a list src from img tag?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I'm building a webapp using sencha touch, and I need to use some images from another website. These images are updated every 10 minutes, so the source of the images is changing all the time. So I don't have an specific url where to get the images.

Can anyone suggest a way to get the source of the images using javascript?

I tried with jsonp, but got nothing more than an error.

I will appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There is two javascript solutions:

1. Ajax request to the website API
2. Load the page into an hidden iframe, onload, fire the update of the image, search for the source image you want in the iframe childrens, then delete the DOM of the iframe